# Generating (not sending) a SMS?

Tags: android, sms

Is it possible to generate an incoming SMS with custom sender and text ?

If not, does it work to change the sender number in sendTextMessage ?

My goal is to generate / send a sms to my phone, while showing custom sender.

I'm not sure which approach should I choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean while debugging/developing with the SDK? If so there is an option to do this with the command line SDK tools, and also in the Eclipse IDE Android SDK tools in the debug screen (lower left).

If this is to implement a reminder consider the notification manager (aka "Status Bar"):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html